# How do I bind to mouseover and mouseleave events when using ng-options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I want to use a directive to bind to the mouseover and mouseleave events for the option elements in the following select element:

```
<select class="form-control" jr-option-bind="" ng-model="vm.selectedPersonalInfo" ng-options="personalInfo as personalInfo.name for personalInfo in vm.personalInfos"></select>
```

This doesn't work.
jr-option-bind is my directive:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var options = element.children();
        options.bind('mouseover', function(){
           console.log('mouseover');
        });
        options.bind('mouseleave', function(){
            console.log('mouseleave');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var options = element.children();
        $(element).on('mouseover', 'option', function(){
           console.log('mouseover');
        });
        $(element).on('mouseleave', 'option', function(){
            console.log('mouseleave');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Charkan, this didn't work for me.  Do you have a working example?

Answer (score 0):

You could also explode the select element like:

```
<select class="form-control" jr-option-bind="" ng-model="vm.selectedPersonalInfo">
    <option ng-repeat="personalInfo as personalInfo.name for personalInfo in vm.personalInfos">
        {{personInfo.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And then add ng-mouseover or ng-mouseleave on the option element like

```
<option ng-mouseleave="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Thanks Luuk, I knew how to this by using ng-repeat.  As a learning thing, I want to see if it's possible using ng-options.

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned from researching this is that IE and Chrome do not allow mouseover or mousenter for the option element in a dropdown.  I decided to use radio buttons.